# RSA256 public key from Google certs failing for one key

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, jwt

To authenticate a google oauth2 token, I'm generating a public key for kid "b863b534069bfc0207197bcf831320d1cdc2cee2" from the modulus (n) and exponent (e) from:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

```
{
"alg": "RS256",
"n": "8h6tCwOYDPtzyFivNaIguQVc_yBO5eOA2kUu_MAN8s4VWn8tIfCbVvcAz3yNwQuGpkdNg8gTk9QmReXl4SE8m7aCa0iRcBBWLyPUt6TM1RkYE51rOGYhjWxo9V8ogMXSBclE6x0t8qFY00l5O34gjYzXtyvyBX7Sw5mGuNLVAzq2nsCTnIsHrIaBy70IKU3FLsJ_PRYyViXP1nfo9872q3mtn7bJ7_hqss0vDgUiNAqPztVIsrZinFbaTgXjLhBlUjFWgJx_g4p76CJkjQ3-puZRU5A0D04KvqQ_0AWcN1Q8pvwQ9V4uGHm6Bop9nUhIcZJYjjlTM9Pkx_JnVOfekw",
"use": "sig",
"kid": "b863b534069bfc0207197bcf831320d1cdc2cee2",
"e": "AQAB",
"kty": "RSA"
}
```

I then create the RSA 256 public key in php with:

```
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64url_decode($cert["n"]), 256);
    $exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64url_decode($cert["e"]), 256);
    $rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
    $rsa->setPublicKey();
    $public_key = $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

This generates public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuopEuQyOKMsQq90I/5on
1nNBPc7stMvsN1HC+Pgyu8nJ1qWwaAAqIv4edo2oG/Bo3eg6p+OjG3nbFL62S6hE
aJLUVfxhW5GQuxQlsvaA2MsZuZCRyKTv8bm641wM+biGVZLiDsLRylVdpxf4aGa9
9zZw+QZMVKL4f9B4SunyTugTaCIu8LBOQesCQp/QJaUjqMDhfEvoFQXiCn6zo3rW
EWBiKxiFBizH9jSfWimJecFhn0Vlv/Vs7pRb0X2y66VS3gTvR6/A3ooNz3tYAJPM
GoE8fAiEghYXXHjmWmgdRx9Qt9sa/ACwv7yx0Th27fw+rrsMSrUyaqRpn/fjIMTu
sQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This same method worked with dozens of other RS256 kid's from google, but the public key does not work with this particular kid.

I am verifying the signature with:

```
openssl_verify($payload_to_verify, $safe_signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
```

Which responds with '0' for failure.

Edit #2: Found google's version of the public key at:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8h6tCwOYDPtzyFivNaIg
uQVc/yBO5eOA2kUu/MAN8s4VWn8tIfCbVvcAz3yNwQuGpkdNg8gTk9QmReXl4SE8
m7aCa0iRcBBWLyPUt6TM1RkYE51rOGYhjWxo9V8ogMXSBclE6x0t8qFY00l5O34g
jYzXtyvyBX7Sw5mGuNLVAzq2nsCTnIsHrIaBy70IKU3FLsJ/PRYyViXP1nfo9872
q3mtn7bJ7/hqss0vDgUiNAqPztVIsrZinFbaTgXjLhBlUjFWgJx/g4p76CJkjQ3+
puZRU5A0D04KvqQ/0AWcN1Q8pvwQ9V4uGHm6Bop9nUhIcZJYjjlTM9Pkx/JnVOfe
kwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My generated public key is different. Why my generated public key is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the key is not correctly converted by the RSA Crypt package.

- [Wrong key](https://lapo.it/asn1js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
- [Good key](https://lapo.it/asn1js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

I tried to convert that key with another application ([web-token/jwt-app](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-app)) and I got the same result as the one provided by Google.

```
curl -OL https://github.com/web-token/jwt-app/raw/gh-pages/jose.phar
curl -OL https://github.com/web-token/jwt-app/raw/gh-pages/jose.phar.pubkey

chmod +x jose.phar
./jose.phar key:convert:pkcs1 '{"alg": "RS256","n": "8h6tCwOYDPtzyFivNaIguQVc_yBO5eOA2kUu_MAN8s4VWn8tIfCbVvcAz3yNwQuGpkdNg8gTk9QmReXl4SE8m7aCa0iRcBBWLyPUt6TM1RkYE51rOGYhjWxo9V8ogMXSBclE6x0t8qFY00l5O34gjYzXtyvyBX7Sw5mGuNLVAzq2nsCTnIsHrIaBy70IKU3FLsJ_PRYyViXP1nfo9872q3mtn7bJ7_hqss0vDgUiNAqPztVIsrZinFbaTgXjLhBlUjFWgJx_g4p76CJkjQ3-puZRU5A0D04KvqQ_0AWcN1Q8pvwQ9V4uGHm6Bop9nUhIcZJYjjlTM9Pkx_JnVOfekw","use": "sig","kid": "b863b534069bfc0207197bcf831320d1cdc2cee2","e": "AQAB","kty": "RSA"}'
```

Best would be to warn [phpseclib/phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) about that issue.

Comment: I am using an older version of \Crypt\RSA.php, so you are probably correct. I will do some more testing with a current version.